# How to handle Japanese file name in URL while downloading file. Facing problem in IE and FireFox

Tags: java, tomcat, url, encode

I am facing a problem while downloading files with the Japanese file name. I have already set the character encoding to UTF-8. It gets works with local tomcat but it's not working Ec2 server. IE and firefox giving problems while downloading files. Chrome browser working properly.

```
        fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8");
        modRewriteFileName = URLEncoder.encode(modRewriteFileName,"UTF-8");
        
        URL url = new URL(fileURL + modRewriteFileName);
        inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
```

getting this error while downloading file from IE browser

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:483)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:502)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
```

Comment: Please describe the problems.  What is "not working".  How is it "not working".

Comment: @StephenC   It's working on other browsers. but I am facing an issue in the Only IE browser while downloading a file with a Japanese name.

Comment: If the error is on url.openConnection then try "ISO-8859-1" - maybe the server is configured wrong. Otherwise go for `fileURL` being "...?file=" and not ".../". Also the modRewriteFileName should be logged.

Comment: @JoopEggen where do I check the server configuration and which file I need to do changes can you please help me with it.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is the HTTP default, so no need to try much. I do not remember how to config Tomcat. Using a test.jsp with a request parameter, URLEncoded, can be used to determine the actiual encoding. First I would log or debug all.

Comment: I don't see where in your code you encode Japanize file name and why did you use UTF-8 character encoding for URL?